# Source for iPhone graphics, icons, images?

Tags: iphone, xcode, graphics

I have found several great sources for iPhone icons, but are there any "stock" graphics available (free or paid) for other UI elements? For instance, a UITableView skin, background images, or custom control artwork.

Comment: I'm a bit torn on this one. Is this programming related?

Comment: @lc Kind of, but not really. BUT there are many questions on graphics and icons for iPhone that has not been closed, so I suggest you keep this open.

Answer (score 3):

Try [365psd.com](http://365psd.com) ... they give you the psd's so you can rescale or customize the elements to match your app ... it's free and completely awesome.

I'm amending this to add [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/) (that's three B's) ... it's more of a showcase for artists and interface designers, but in many cases you'll find folks who post links to download and use some of their elements ... I'm also reiterating that 365psd is still my number one favorite place.

I'm amending my amendment, to also add [DesignMoo](http://designmoo.com/), which is in the same vein as 365PSD, free vectors, textures, UI elements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some decent success with finding graphics on http://www.iconfinder.com/

Comment: That's a nice website, but I'm all set with icons. This question is about non-icon artwork.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this:

[findicons.com](http://findicons.com/)

[webdesignledger.com](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/15-must-have-minimalist-icon-sets)

[defaulticon.com](http://www.defaulticon.com/)

Answer (score 1):

**Tappatics is probably your best bet. http://www.tapptics.com/
They have a bunch of resources, although they require payment it looks like they have quite a few resources. ($197, is a bit much if you ask me though)**

If you want custom artwork, there are designers who post on Dribbble.com and there are some sites that feature awesome custom work, but they won't straight up give you an psd. 
http://creattica.com/mobile/latest-designs
[http://www.dribbble.com](http://dribble.com)

Here is an awesome site for tutorials and mobile programming in general:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-design-tutorials/better-apps-by-design/

in that page they have a list of links and a bunch of tutorial which could help:

```
PSDTuts+ – Free, but with Premium Available 
PixelBeam – Free 
365 PSD -Free
Premium Pixels – Free 
GraphicRiver – Paid
```

Example of the resources: http://www.tapptics.com/design-templates-for-iphone-iphone-4/

There are of course just raw iPhone PSD's with the stock UI's (namely [teehan+lax's](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/) or [this](http://365psd.com/day/308/)) but my impression is that you need custom/"not as stock" graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Direct Download PSD's

**iPhone 4 GUI (Retina Display)**: http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/iphone-4-guid-psd-retina-display/

**iPhone4 GUI elem** (by Yahoo, non PSD) http://graffletopia.com/stencils/392

**iPhone4 GUI elem** (non PSD) http://cypher7.deviantart.com/art/inSET-HD-177817078

**iPad GUI stencils**: http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/ipad-stencil-for-omnigraffle/

**iPhone4**: http://www.sebastiengabriel.com/blog/resource-for-designer-psd-9/

**iPad2**: http://www.sebastiengabriel.com/blog/ressources-pour-designer-psd-2/

**misc iPhone/iPad**

iPad and Paper Stack Icon - http://365psd.com/day/2-70/

.. etc.

Let me know if you want me to keep going. ATB.

Answer (score 0):

The collection here is decent, esp if you are looking for images used in some other apps - http://release78.org/ic/